# Magento format DateTime using Configuration options

Tags: magento

In a Magento PHP module, how can I programmatically echo a DateTime (UTC) variable formatted using Magento's Configuration options (ie System > Configuration > Catalog > Date & Time Custom Options)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mage::helper('core')->formatTime($time=null, $format='short', $showDate=false);`

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/guide-through-magentos-timezones/